# Equivalent of setdefault in Go?

Tags: python, go

I can do:

```
_, ok := some_go_map[a_key]
```

to test for existence of key.

But I've been spoiled by Python's dict's `setdefault` method (if a key does not have value set in a "map" [dict == associative array], set it to a given default, then get it; otherwise just get).

Wondering if there's some idiom in Go to achieve the same thing?

Comment: In python, you can always use `defaultdict`.

Comment: Erm I know but my question is about Go having similar thing to Python (setdefault).

Comment: You might know, but whenever a key doesn't already exist in a map, Go gives you the "zero value" of the value type. That's `""` for `string`s, `0` for `int`s, `nil` for a bunch of nillable types. So if zero is an OK default value, you're in luck. If not, either of the answers below look good--here's a variation of their code that allows you to both use `[]` for Go's built-in behabvior and `SetDefault` for set-with-(nonzero)-default, on the same dictionary: http://play.golang.org/p/5SIJSWNWO7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always define it yourself:

```
func setDefault(h map[string]int, k string, v int) (set bool, r int) {
    if r, set = h[k]; !set {
        h[k] = v
        r = v
        set = true
    }
    return
}
```

But no, it's not in the stdlib. Usually, you'd just do this inline.

Answer (score 15):

Note that Go's default behavior is to return the "[zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)" for the value type (e.g., `0` or `""`) when a looked-up key's missing, so if the default you want happens to be that, you're all set already.

Riffing off Buddy and larsmans' answers, here's code that attaches a new method to a named `Dict` type, so you can either use `d[key]` for Go's built-in behavior or `d.SetDefault(key, val)`--

http://play.golang.org/p/5SIJSWNWO7

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Dict map[string]float64

func (d Dict) SetDefault(key string, val float64) (result float64) {
    if v, ok := d[key]; ok {
        return v
    } else {
        d[key] = val
        return val
    }
}

func main() {
    dd := Dict{}
    dd["a"] = 3
    fmt.Println(dd.SetDefault("a", 1))
    fmt.Println(dd.SetDefault("b", 2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't something like that built in. You could add a type to help out

http://play.golang.org/p/pz34p7w6fP

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Default struct {
    vals     map[string]int
    defaults int
}

func (d *Default) Get(key string) int {
    if val, ok := d.vals[key]; ok {
        return val
    }
    return d.defaults
}

func main() {
    someMap := Default{map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, 5}
    fmt.Println(someMap.Get("foo"))
    fmt.Println(someMap.Get("doesn't exist"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to generics, it may now look something like this

```golang
// SetDefault sets the value of k to def if k is not in m.
// If m is nil, it creates a new map.
// Returns map and value of k or def if k is not in m.
func SetDefault[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M, k K, def V) (resMap M, v V) {
    if v, ok := m[k]; ok {
        return m, v
    } else if m == nil {
        return map[K]V{k: def}, def
    }

    m[k] = def

    return m, def
}
```

In addition, you can also create `GetDefault`

```golang
// GetDefault returns the value of k in m or def if k is not in m.
func GetDefault[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M, k K, def V) V {
    if v, ok := m[k]; ok {
        return v
    }

    return def
}
```